# Pre process file before file_get_contents

Tags: php, preprocessor, file-get-contents

I was wondering, in PHP, if there was a way to get PHP to pre-process a file before writing it to a string.

Example:
I have index.php, which instantiates a class which calls `file_get_contents` depending on what GET parameter has been passed in via the .htaccess.

I have some variables in the index.php such as `$error = 'This is an error';`

In one of my files that I'm bringing back with `file_get_contents`, I have:
`<?php if ($error): echo $error; endif; ?>` which of course does not get processed due to `file_get_contents` literally just writing all content to a string.

Anyone got any idea on how to process the PHP before bringing back the file, or bringing back the file with the PHP still in place?

**Please** do not tell me to use a function like `include` as I need to write the file to a string to be able to perform a `str_replace` on certain words.

Thanks.

Comment: You could perhaps use `eval()`, but if you have to stoop to that you would be well advised to find a better way.

Comment: Not sure why this is getting downvoted...
Doesn't help me at all.
If people are downvoting because it's so 'easy' maybe someone should help out?

Comment: Got to be a better approach to the whole thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why this question got downvoted like crazy... But I worked it out after a lot of searching. The code I needed was:

```
    ob_start();
    include $this->templateDir . $this->theme . '/' . $page . '.php';
    $pageContent = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
```

Thanks for the downvotes and attempts to solve my problem. Much appreciated.

Inb4 downvotes on this post.